# How to fix "fatal error: boost/asio.hpp: no such file or directory"?

Tags: c++, macos, boost-asio, macos-mojave

I have installed boost using homebrew and it was working before I followed some steps to try and get gdb debugger working but now after I followed the steps and restarted, I can't even compile my program. I have googled all over the place for the last 2 hours and I cannot figure this out.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling boost and anything else that I could find on google or stackoverflow but nothing is working and I have an assignment due tomorrow night and I am freaking out.

Exact error:

```
fatal error: boost/asio.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <boost/asio.hpp>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I have tried compiling a number of ways including:

```
g++ -g -I /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.69.0 battleship_client.cc -lboost_system
```

Comment: Does `/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.69.0/boost/asio.hpp` exist?

Comment: @drescherjm the path on my computer is /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.69.0/include/boost/asio.hpp

Comment: Then you need to fix your include path that you gave to the compiler to use `/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.69.0/include` instead of `/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.69.0`

Comment: @drescherjm If I put the path I just listed, it gives me this: ld: library not found for -lboost_system
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: I think you need to add a -L pathto_boost_libraries. where `pathto_boost_libraries` is the folder containing the libraries.

Comment: THANK YOU, THAT WORKED!

Comment: It could be that. I don't know what you have on your end..

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure the boost include path is passed into your compiler.

The boost lib path will need to be passed into to your linker.

Depending on your environment, you can do this with the system path variable, Visual Studio properties, or as compiler/linker flags.